# Calculating paralel lines coordinates with arbitrary angle

Tags: math, 2d, computational-geometry

We have 2 parallel lines in the 2D space separated by 5 units:

Black - 0,0 -> 20,0

Red - 0,5 -> 20,5

The angle is 0 degrees. We always know the coordinates of the black line and the angle in degrees. The coordinates of the red line needs to be calculated given arbitrary angle.

[image: sample]

Is there any formula for such calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find direction vector for the first line

```
dx = x2 - x1
dy = y2 - y1
```

Normalize it

```
len = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
dx = dx / len
dy = dy / len
```

Get perpendicular vector (note it is "right" normal, for "left" one change signs)

```
nx = dy
ny = -dx
```

Get parallel segment ends with d = parallel distance

```
x3 = x1 + d * nx
y3 = y1 + d * ny
x4 = x2 + d * nx
y4 = y2 + d * ny
```